# transposing data in array using numpy

Tags: numpy

I have list as following and need to be tranposed to a numpy array

```
samplelist= [  [ ['Name-1','Name-2','Name-3']            , ['Age-1','Age-2','Age-3'] ],
               [ ['new_Name_1','new_Name_2','new_Name_3'], ['new_Age_1','new_Age_2','new_Age_3'] ]
             ]
```

Expected Result:

```
samplearray = [ [ ['Name-1','Age-1'],         ['Name-2','Age-2'],        ['Name-3','Age-3'] ],
                [ ['new_Name_1','new_Age_1],  ['new_Name_2','new_Age_2'], ['new_Name_3','new_Age_3'] ]
               ]
```

np.transpose results:

```
np.transpose(a)
array([[['Name-1', 'new_Name_1'],
        ['Age-1', 'new_Age_1']],

       [['Name-2', 'new_Name_2'],
        ['Age-2', 'new_Age_2']],

       [['Name-3', 'new_Name_3'],
        ['Age-3', 'new_Age_3']]], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

Comment: well, what did you tried? Have you googled for "numpy transpose"?

Comment: Yes, I did and I have given the results...

Comment: numpy.transpose gives different than your result. So, it is not directly the transpose I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`samplelist` is a 3-D array.

```
In [58]: samplelist.shape
Out[58]: (2, 2, 3)
```

Using transpose swaps the first and last axes (0 and 2):

```
In [55]: samplelist.T
Out[55]: 
array([[['Name-1', 'new_Name_1'],
        ['Age-1', 'new_Age_1']],

       [['Name-2', 'new_Name_2'],
        ['Age-2', 'new_Age_2']],

       [['Name-3', 'new_Name_3'],
        ['Age-3', 'new_Age_3']]], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [57]: samplelist.swapaxes(0,2)
Out[57]: 
array([[['Name-1', 'new_Name_1'],
        ['Age-1', 'new_Age_1']],

       [['Name-2', 'new_Name_2'],
        ['Age-2', 'new_Age_2']],

       [['Name-3', 'new_Name_3'],
        ['Age-3', 'new_Age_3']]], 
      dtype='|S10')
```

To get the desired array, swap axes 1 and 2:

```
import numpy as np
samplelist = np.array([
    [ ['Name-1','Name-2','Name-3']            , ['Age-1','Age-2','Age-3'] ],
    [ ['new_Name_1','new_Name_2','new_Name_3'], ['new_Age_1','new_Age_2','new_Age_3'] ]
    ])

print(samplelist.swapaxes(1,2))
# [[['Name-1' 'Age-1']
#   ['Name-2' 'Age-2']
#   ['Name-3' 'Age-3']]

#  [['new_Name_1' 'new_Age_1']
#   ['new_Name_2' 'new_Age_2']
#   ['new_Name_3' 'new_Age_3']]]
```